# Scalaz: Convert ValidationNel of ValidationNel to ValidationNel

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

How do I convert

```
val from: ValidationNel[E, ValidationNel[E, T]]
```

to

```
val to: ValidationNel[E, T]
```

while capturing all validation errors?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `from.fold(Failure(_), identity)`.

In general, flatMap(identity) or .join works for any Monad for turning F[F[A]] into F[A], however, Validation is not a Monad, and the flatMap / join methods for Validation are deprecated.

Comment: `flatMap` is still around, just more explicit https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Validation.scala#L373-L376

Answer (score 1):

Just `flatMap` that `ValidationNel`:

```
from.flatMap(identity)
```